# Limiting number of API call from each browser/client/machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, service

I have a publically exposed API, this is kind of a demo API.
I want to limit access from browser/client/machine to just 2 calls.

I was thinking to use IP to uniquely identify the client and limit it but CGNAT could be an issue so a lot of users can be denied the access if any one user under that IP uses it.

What are other way to achieve it?

API is in AWS.

**Tried IP based solution but found CGNAT can be a issue.**

Comment: Require each client to supply a unique API key. Or investigate (probably not very reliable) browser fingerprint techniques.

Comment: Hi Thanks, Its not just Machine clients, there could be browsers too. I guess exposing API key to browser for API call is not safe. Agreed browser fingerprint techniques are not that reliable.